# Is there a way to associate one stylesheet(s) for one particular template in Meteor?

Tags: css, meteor

The way it works now, Meteor automatically finds CSS files in the client directory and renders it without having to call it in the HTML's header tag.

However, how would I be able (if it's even remotely possible) to associate one particular CSS file or files to just one HTML page?

I recently purchased a theme for one section of my website that I didn't want to bother creating myself, since I hate doing UI for my main page myself. But when I place the CSS files of this template with the ones I have for the other template I use, one template's CSS files overwrite the other, so everything ends up looking like a huge jumbled mess.

I hope I'm being clear with my question. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

So, if there's not a way to keep the file from being included in meteor, you could add a class to the body tag of the page you want the styles to appear in, then prepend that class to the beginning of the styles in your new stylesheet, ex: .yourBodyClass#stylehseetID, .yourBodyClass.stylesheetClass

Answer (score 0):

if you put your stylesheet in the public folder, it will be treated as a static file, but then it should go in the header which is rendered by Meteor, and since Meteor is a single page app (SPA), it only has one header for the whole application.

If you need specific styles for a page, you can use some prefix for your css classes. That's probably the easiest.